# HDMI dual screen disappears when I turn the screen on

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I'm very new to Linux, but I've installed Ubuntu 16.04LTS and its running smoothly. But I'd love to be able to dual (or even single) screen to my TV via a long HDMI cable I have from computer to the TV room. Worked fine under OS X.

I have my main screen connected via DVI. Then my TV via the sole HDMI connection on my internal intel graphics card.

When I have the TV off, Screen display shows the TV to the right of my normal screen. And xrandr shows HDMI-2. 
When I turn the TV on, the TV disappears from 'Screen Display' and xrandr says HDMI-2 disconnected.

I've tried using the "intel graphics tool for Linux" and even the Nvidia drivers thingy as suggested elsewhere. No dice.

**my system**

```
:~$ sudo lshw -C video
[sudo] password for : 
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:27 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
**xrandr output with tv on**
:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Does anyone have any advice? I'm not great with all this but I've stumbled through so far. Much appreciated even for reading this far, thanks, 
Tom

**xrandr output with tv off (just dvi connected)**

```
:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-2 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 580mm x 330mm
   1360x768      59.80 +
   1920x1080     60.00*   50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    60.00    50.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       72.81    60.00    59.94  **
```